# Marvel Future Fight can't disable notifications

Tags: marvel-future-fight

I have installed Marvel Future Fight v3.2.0 on my Android phone (Xperia Z1).

In the Settings, it has a few tabs regarding different types of settings.

I intend to disable notifications, so I selected the *Alert* tab.

[image]

When I change to a tab other than ALERT, I can see different settings but *when I change to the ALERT tab, it stucks there* - meaning that even if I click another tab, I still see the *All Notifications (on/off)* settings.

If I select the *Option* tab **after Alert**:

[image]

Also, when I change it to off, the OK button is not saving the setting.

Looks like a bug or I try to set it wrong. I tried to reinstall it but no change.

Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but those were only workarounds. As of version *3.5.1*, **the issue has been fixed**.

Answer (score 2):

If the app doesn't allow you to turn the notifications off, you can still ask android to do it for you.

In Settings/Sound and Notifications/ (Sometimes just Settings/Notifications), you have a list of all installed applications, and can turn notification to off for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this indeed is the case. I have been trying to turn them off for a while too. Seems to be a 'convenient' bug for the developers.

Comment: What kind of phone do you use it on?